# Migrate SQL Server 2008 databases to 2016

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-migration

We are processing to migrate SQL Server databases from 2008 to 2016.

We are searching now for expired function or utilities used in SQL Server 2008 and not available in SQL Server 2016 before migration.

Do you have reference for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are few features removed in SQL Server 2016 (from [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx)):

- SQL Server 2016 is a 64-bit application. 32-bit installation is discontinued, though some elements run as 32-bit components
- Compatibility level 90 is discontinued. For more information, see [ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx).

Though you are migrating from SQL Server 2008 directly to SQL Server 2016, you need to consider the removed features of SQL Server 2012 & SQL Server 2014 as well

- [Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms144262(v=sql.120))
- [Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms144262(v=sql.110))